# next Node in Node Class

Tags: java, class

I have this node class, I was wondering how does the program recognize that the Node next is actually the next node? and why would I want to assign it to null please? Detailed explanation would be greatly appreciated.

```
package LinearNode;
import dataobjects.*;


public class Node
{

public Node next;
public AnyClass obj;

public Node(AnyClass newObj)
{
    next = null; 
    obj = newObj;
}

public void show()
{
    System.out.println(obj.getData());
}

public void editNode()
{
    obj.editData();
}

public Node getNext()
{
    return next;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the responsibility of the programmer to properly assemble and use the data structures he chooses. The `next` node points to a reference of what is assumed to be the 'next' node in the linked list, but Java can't tell you if you've linked them correctly or not. `null` is often used to represent the end of the list (as opposed to say a circular linked list, in which case head and tail pointers may be used instead of null). Documentation on the linked list data structure can be found on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) and also [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/08/c-linked-list-example/), though the examples are written in C.

Answer (score 1):

A Node is typically used in a linked list, and the node with a null next node is the last one of the list (since it doesn't have any next node).

The next node of a node will be the one you initialize, by doing

```
someNode.next = someOtherNode;
```

Note that fields should be private by default, and should almost never be public. Use methods to modify the state of objects.